# Instance Member issue concerning a public method in a public class

Tags: c#, static-members

Inside of a public class:

```
    public static class LogReporting
```

I have the following method:

```
    public void RunTimerJobs()
    {
        SPAdministrationWebApplication centralAdmin = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
        try
        {
            foreach (SPService service in centralAdmin.Farm.Services)
            {
                Guid traceGuid = new Guid("d3beda82-38f4-4bc7-874f-ad45cebc9b35");
                Guid eventGuid = new Guid("3ea057b3-0391-4c33-ac8d-412aecdda97d");

                var traceJob =
                    from jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions
                    where jobDefinition.Id == traceGuid
                    select jobDefinition;

                if (traceJob != null && traceJob.Count() == 1)
                {
                    traceJob.First().RunNow();
                }

                var eventJob =
                    from jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions
                    where jobDefinition.Id == eventGuid
                    select jobDefinition;

                if (eventJob != null && eventJob.Count() == 1)
                {
                    eventJob.First().RunNow();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Loggers.SharePointLogger logger = new Loggers.SharePointLogger();
            //logger.WriteTrace(ex.Message, LogProduct.MonitoringView, LogTraceSeverity.Unexpected);
        }
```

However it will not allow me to compile citing that `RunTimerJobs()` "cannot declare instance members in a static class"
To my knowledge, none of the 'instance members' I declare are able to be labeled as `static`, so is there just a fundamental issue with the setup (i.e. a static class) or am I missing some little snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is static thus you cannot have any instance members because you will never instantiate the class.

To be able to use the `RunTimerJobs()` method you would need to create an `instance` of the `LogReporting` class, i.e.

```
LogReporting logReporting = new LogReporting();
logReporting.RunTimerJobs();
```

This obviously won't work though because your class is defined as `static` and you **cannot** create instances of it.

Either make your method `static` or remove the `static` keyword from your `class` declaration - depending on what you require.

I see no instance related logic in your method so *it should* be safe to mark it as `static`.

**Remember**

> Classes can have a mixture of instance and static members as long as the class isn't marked **static**.

**And**

> Only mark classes as static when you know that ALL members (properties, methods etc...) will be static as well.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler's being pretty clear here. You're declaring a *static* class, and static classes can only contain *static* members. So this is okay:

```
public class NonStaticClass
{
    public void InstanceMethod() {}
}
```

And this is okay:

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static void StaticMethod() {}
}
```

But this isn't:

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public void InstanceMethod() {}
}
```

If you wanted to declare instance members, why did you declare `LogReporting` as a static class?

Comment: I am going in and adding work to a pre-existing file.  At the team lead's suggestion I put it inside this `LogReporting`.  I am assuming he forgot/neglected that it was a static class.

Comment: @wjhguitarman Looking at your code, it isn't performing any instance related logic so it should be safe to assume that you can mark the `RunTimerJobs()` method as static.

Answer (score 1):

When class marked as **static**, then *all it's members should be static* (instances creation is not allowed). You can read more about static classes on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

So, if you want to have instance (non-static) method, then remove **static** keyword from class definition:

```
public class LogReporting
{
     public void RunTimerJobs()
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

In this case you should create `LogReporting` instance to call your method:

```
LogReporting log = new LogReporting();
log.RunTimerJobs();
```

Another option for you - making your method **static**:

```
public static class LogReporting
{
     public static void RunTimerJobs()
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

In this case you don't need instance of `LogReporting`:

```
LogReporting.RunTimerJobs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

`public static void RunTimerJobs()`

Answer (score 0):

For a static class, the members must also be static. If you are unable make the members static, then you must make the class non-static as well.

It's generally a good idea to use non-static classes if you can, as static classes increase the complexity of unit testing as they cannot be mocked out easily. Of course if you have a legitimate need to use a static class, then by all means do so.